# Vertical X and Y error

Tags: html, css

(This is mainly CSS)
I've created a vertical line...Just cuz...And I'm trying to be able to make change where it is (X and Y Coords.) Can someone help me with this?

code:

```
.vertical {
    X: div.id;
    Y: div.id;
    border-left: 2px solid #555555;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using top and left

```
.vertical {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #555555;
}
```